# PDFMiner enoding to UTF-8

Tags: python, python-2.7, pdfminer

I am using PDFMiner to convert PDF to text. Then I would like to encode it to [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) since the text is in [Hebrew](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Hebrew#Proper_noun).

This is the code of the PDFMiner:

```
from pdfminer.pdfdocument import PDFDocument
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from cStringIO import StringIO
from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFParser


def convert_pdf_to_txt(path):
    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    retstr = StringIO()
    codec = 'utf-8'
    laparams = LAParams()
    device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, codec=codec, laparams=laparams)

    fp = file(path, 'rb')

    parser = PDFParser(fp)
    doc = PDFDocument(parser)
    parser.set_document(doc)

    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
    password = ""
    maxpages = 0
    caching = True
    pagenos=set()

    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp, pagenos, maxpages=maxpages,  password=password,caching=caching, check_extractable=True):
    interpreter.process_page(page)

    text = retstr.getvalue()

    fp.close()
    device.close()
    retstr.close()
    return text
```

Now when I try to print it:

```
    elif file[-4:] == ".pdf":
    text = convert_pdf_to_txt("C:\Users\Vadim\Desktop\Python\New_cvs\\" + file)
    print text
```

It brings me the text backwards like "rac" instead of "car", but in Hebrew.

How do I correct it?

I tried tuple slicing, but then it will reverse the mail texts and phone number texts, so it's not an option.

```
''.join(reversed(myString))
```

Also not an option :(